# Typescript is not performing typecheck

Tags: typescript, typechecking

I'm trying to take advantage of the TypeScript typecheck, but I'm stuck with the following code:

```ts
abstract class Mammal {
  abstract breed(other: Mammal);
}

class Dog extends Mammal {
  breed(other: Dog) {}
}

class Cat extends Mammal {
  breed(other: Cat) {}
}

const toby = new Dog();
const lucy = new Dog();
const luna = new Cat();

toby.breed(lucy); // OK
toby.breed(luna); // Works, but it shouldn't since luna is a Cat!
```

It seems like TypeScript is performing some kind of duck typing here and is considering `Dog == Cat`. How can I get the typechecker to reject this code?

> **Sidenote**: This is how I would do this in Rust:
>
> ```rust
> trait Mammal {
>     fn breed(&self, other: &Self);
> }
>
> struct Cat {}
>
> impl Mammal for Cat {
>     fn breed(&self, _other: &Self) {}
> }
>
> struct Dog {}
>
> impl Mammal for Dog {
>     fn breed(&self, _other: &Self) {}
> }
>
> fn main() {
>     let toby = Dog{};
>     let lucy = Dog{};
>     let luna = Cat{};
>
>     toby.breed(&lucy);
>     toby.breed(&luna); // expected struct `Dog`, found struct `Cat`
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript is [structurally typed](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-structural-typing) (thanks to @jcalz).

> The idea behind structural typing is that two types are compatible if their members are compatible.

Not so elegant but working: You can add a dummy property to make some differences between the classes ([Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=abstract%20class%20Mammal%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20abstract%20breed(other%3A%20Mammal)%3Avoid%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Dog%20extends%20Mammal%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20dummy1%20%3D%20undefined%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20breed(other%3A%20Dog)%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Cat%20extends%20Mammal%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20private%20dummy2%20%3D%20undefined%3B%0D%0A%20%20breed(other%3A%20Cat)%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20toby%20%3D%20new%20Dog()%3B%0D%0Aconst%20lucy%20%3D%20new%20Dog()%3B%0D%0Aconst%20luna%20%3D%20new%20Cat()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atoby.breed(lucy)%3B%20%2F%2F%20OK%0D%0Atoby.breed(luna)%3B%20%2F%2F%20Error)):

```
abstract class Mammal {
  abstract breed(other: this): void; // Bonus: Here you can make use of Polymorphic this types
}

class Dog extends Mammal {
    private dummy1 = undefined;
    breed(other: Dog) {}
}

class Cat extends Mammal {
  private dummy2 = undefined;
  breed(other: Cat) {}
}

const toby = new Dog();
const lucy = new Dog();
const luna = new Cat();

toby.breed(lucy); // OK
toby.breed(luna); // Error
```

Bonus: You can make use of [Polymorphic this types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) (thanks to @jcalz) in your base class.

```
abstract breed(other: this): void;
```

Comment: This is the right answer; TypeScript is [structurally typed](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-structural-typing), and the person asking the question might not be used to that.  Also, `abstract breed(other: this): void` might be a more appropriate signature.